# Impedance matching an amplifier near 1 dB compression point

Tags: amplifier, rf, impedance-matching

I am using a RF amplifier (model: Minicircuits LZY-22+) to drive 6.5 MHz oscillation in a coil. I am using an antenna tuner (model: MFJ-969) to impedance-match the output of the amplifier to the coil. Up to some power (~40 dBm), I can get pretty good matching with almost no reflection (SWR < 1.1). But as I try to increase power beyond 40 dBm, SWR goes up and it's hard to keep it below the value of 2 while I try to optimize the matching again. I noticed that this transition seems to be close to the 1dB compression point of the amplifier.

Q1: Does the nonlinearity of the amplifier near 1 dB point actually mean that the impedance is changing, and hence I have to re-optimize?

Q2: Why would the SWR show an increasing lower bound near the 1 dB point, even after trying to re-optimize the tuner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: Does the nonlinearity of the amplifier near 1 dB point actually
>   mean that the impedance is changing, and hence I have to re-optimize?

Yes, the impedance changes. Impedance matching is a concept based on the fact that the system behaves **linearly**. That means doubling the input signal will double all internal signals and the output signal. Also any reflections will double.

Up until the 1 dB compression point the amplifier behaves in a linear (enough) way so that the impedance matching works as expected.

However at the 1 dB compression point the output signal of the amplifier is 1 dB lower than what it should have been if it was an ideal amplifier. That output signal being lower than expected is **non linear** behavior and that harms the impedance matching.

You could try and tune for that specific situation (the 1 dB compression point) but even if you find such a point it will mean that at lower power signals, the impedance matching will be less optimal. You'll need to compromise in that respect, good small signal matching **or** best you can get large signal matching **or** a compromise between those two.

> Q2: Why would the SWR show an increasing lower bound near the 1 dB
>   point, even after trying to re-optimize the tuner?

I am unsure why this is but I think it is a consequence of the non-linear behavior I explained above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding Q1, I would like to know more in details. Gain defines a proportional relationship between $V_{out}$ and $V_{in}$. This linear relationship stays constant until the 1dB point. But impedance is defined as $Z = V/I$, so it's not immediately clear how the change in behavior of $V_{out}/V_{in}$ affects values of $V/I$ in the system.

Comment: Actually, when you say "reflections will double", it means reflected voltage (power) increases linearly until the 1dB point, and I can now partially see how the nonlinear change in reflected power implies change in impedance matching.

Comment: For a linear system Z = V/I remains valid independent of the amplitude of V and I. At the 1 dB compression point, the system isn't linear anymore. If the signal is a sine wave then the **peaks of the sinewave** will not be treated in a linear way. That means the impedance changes as Z = V/I isn't the same as what it is for the parts of the sinewave close to zero (small value).